# python requests library: Function to get response from appended path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to GET the value of a THING on Thingworx platform. I have the below code which achieves the result.

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://academic.cloud.thingworx.com/Thingworx/Things/weatherrover1/Properties/battery'

headers = {'appKey': 'fdb123fc-e369-483b-baa5-8445bd8746ee',
           'Accept': 'application/json'}

getreq = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But I'm trying to break down the URL to basic URL until `'https://academic.cloud.thingworx.com/'` and define variables for what follows and get response. But it fails. Below is the code I tried.

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://academic.cloud.thingworx.com/'
params = { 'Platform': 'Thingworx',
           'Things': 'Things',
           'Entity':'Things',
           'Thing_Name':'weatherrover1',
           'Properties':'Properties',
           'Property_Name':'battery'}

getreq = requests.get(url, params = params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's wrong with just using the full URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `params` argument is *purely* for defining the query parameters, the part after a `?` in the URL.

You added *URL path elements* to your `params`, that won't get you the URL you want, because the URL path is the part *before* the `?` in a URL. You can use [*string formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to expand the path.

String formatting can use templates, so the URL could be:

```
url_template = 'https://academic.cloud.thingworx.com/{platform}/{entity}/{entity_name}/Properties/{property}'
```

and then each `{...}` placeholder name can be taken from a dictionary:

```
url_parts = {
    'entity': 'Things',
    'platform': 'Thingworx',
    'entity': 'Things',
    'entity_name': 'weatherrover1',
    'property': 'battery'
}

url_template.format(**url_parts)
```

Use the `url_template.format(**url_parts)` result in a `requests.get()` call:

```
response = requests.get(url_template.format(**url_parts), headers=headers)
```